# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes - Subtracting series from each row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
0     21
1    305
2    100
3      0
4    196
5     10
6    959
7    705
8     20
9     49
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I'm trying to subtract the above series from each row in this dataframe below.

```
    0      1     2      3      4    5       6    7      8     9
0  69    320   127    164    211    6     721  723      2    20
1  85  140.2  44.8  234.9  171.3  5.5  1047.6  704   23.5  52.5
2  36    275    99    127    184   13     810  790  25.75  64.5
3  10    304     0    140    214    6     895  722     19    51
4  46    318   126      0    210    6     861  737   17.5    48
```

This doesn't seem to work

```
    for index, row in test.iterrows():
        print(row.iloc[:-1])
        print(X.head(5))
        print((X.sub(row.iloc[:-1], axis=1)))
```

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (930,) (10,)

Comment: It is dupe :( `df = df.sub(s, axis=1)`

Comment: Okay, found a dupe.

Comment: In your particular case, you'll want `df.sub(s.values, axis=1)` to prevent index misalignment issues.